# Git merge and diff

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, branch

I have a question about the use of git.

Actually I have two branch in my repository (feature-2, feature-certification). Now I've received a source code from another user and I need to compare his files with my branch (feature-certification). Those files are not under git or remote branch, it's just a folder with files.

What I tried:
I created a new branch and added all the files that I've received then I pushed to the new branch but when I tried to merge into feature-certification I noticed that ALL files are treated like new even when they're not new

Is there any way to check the diff between my branch and the files of the other folder that I have?

Comment: Did you put them in the same folder? Or different folders?

Comment: Actually I have my working repo in one directory and the source code that I've received in other folder

Comment: That’s why then. As you’ve added new files, not updated any.

Comment: How should I proceed? In my working directory just copy and paste the new files? (This would replace some files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my working directory just copy and paste the new files?

Yes, as long as your working directory is clean, meaning all your current files are added and committed.

Then you can copy/overwrite your files with the new ones: a git status/git diff will show you the differences.

At any point, you can get back to your original state with `git reset --hard`.

---

A less intrusive option would be:

```
 cd /path/to/my/repo
 git --work-tree=/path/to/receives/files/folder diff
```

That would show you the difference between the *common* files and your current index.